# With a given point, find the curve that intersects zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

## Background

For a pseudo-trajectory of a cannon, I am to find, with a given point maximum $(M_x,M_y)$, the equation of the curve that intersects the origin and the point $(2M_x,0)$. I have the equation $f(x)=m\left(x-M_x\right)^2+M_y$ that will have its maximum at the point $(M_x,M_y)$, but I am thus far unable to find an $m$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(2M_x)=0$ (restating the required intersects). All I know is that $m<0$ must hold, or else the equations maximum would be $\infty$.

## Question

What might variable $m$ be and how might I find it?

**[Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5wbbo6ikvv)**

Comment: Notice that: $(2M_x - M_x)^2 = (-M_x)^2$, you'll conclude that $m = \frac{M_y}{M_x^2}$.

Comment: Missed a minus sign. Should be $m=-\frac{M_y}{M_x^2}$

Comment: Yep, my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parabola intersects the point $(2M_x,0)$ then the following equation must hold
$$0 =m(2M_x-M_x)^2+M_y=mM_x^2+M_y$$
which implies that
$$m = -\frac{M_y}{M_x^2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much to your contributions! Out of curiosity: Why must the first equation hold?

Comment: Because the parabola passes through $(2M_x, 0)$. i.e. $(2M_x,0)=(2M_x,f(2M_x))\implies f(2m_x)=0$